# How to convert/transmux ismv to mp4 or wmv?

Tags: video, video-conversion

How can I convert/transmux Smooth Streaming ismv files to mp4 or wmv?
I've often read about mp4split but it doesn't seem to be freely available any more.

Comment: MP4Split was available here http://h264.code-shop.com/download/mp4split-2.2.0.tar.gz but apparently you now need to pay for it: http://www.unified-streaming.com/support/forum/setup/mp4split-cant-be-downloaded-http-error-forbidden/

Comment: But possibly you can get it like this: http://docs.unified-streaming.com/installation/evaluation.html#evaluation-fasttrack -- I will check later.